# Finding intervals of uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Given a series of functions, how do we find the interval/region of uniform convergence?? Is there any technique to go about solving this problem??

As for example, consider a series $\sum \frac{\log {n}}{n^{x}}$.  The question asks to find the intervals/regions of uniform convergence.

So far, what I have done is prove that the series converges pointwise for $x \gt 1$. But, how do I go ahead and find the intervals/regions of uniform convergence for this particular problem?? This throws me.

Answer (score 1):

M-Test tells you that $\sum f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on a set $A$ if $|f_n(x)| \leq a_n$ for all $x \in A$ and all $n \geq 1$ with $\sum a_n <\infty$.

In this case we can take $a_n=\frac {\ln n } {n^{1+\epsilon}}$ to see that the series converges uniformly on $[1+\epsilon, \infty)$ for any $\epsilon >0$.

The convergence is not uniform on $(1,\infty)$. Let us prove this by contradiction. If the convergence is uniform there would exist $N$ such that $| \sum\limits_{n=n_1}^{n_2} \frac {\ln  n} {n^{x}}| <1$ for all $x >1$ whenever $n_2,n_1>N$. If we let $x \to 1$ in this we get a contradiction since the series $\sum \frac {\ln  n} {n}$ is divergent.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. Thank you so much. It's very counter-intuitive though that the series doesn't converge uniformly on (1, \infty) although it does on [a, \infty) for every a>1.

Comment: Is there any other general technique too that could be employed to attack this problem in general?? I am wondering if there could be possibilities where the region of uniform convergence is a disjoint union of intervals.

Comment: Depends on the particular series you are analyzing. Typically you find interval(s) on which you have pointwise convergence and then try to analyze what happens near the end points.  But there is no thumb rule. @krishna2016

Comment: I think you just saved my life here. Gonna upvote. Thanks once again.